# how to install opencv2.4.6 using cmake

Tags: c, opencv, visual-studio-2012

can anyone tell me how to install opencv2.4.6 using cmake, I found several tutorials but I can't find the common folder in  **c:\opencv\build_common_ **   to past the **tbb41_20130613oss** folder any idea can I do that.

thanks in advance

Comment: I just followed the tutorial at http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html . Worked perfectly  - but that was on Linux, not with VS.

Comment: I did this a couple of days ago without any problem. Describe your problem more so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this tutorial  and it works now,  if anybody needs this here is the link:
http://4someonehelp.blogspot.in/2013/06/solved-install-opencv-245-using-visual.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the library, and then execute target `install`.

When using `make` it will be

```
make
make install
```

On visual studio You need to select the targets manually (I think).